# How does GridSearchCV use Cross Validation to produce a Model's Score?

Tags: scikit-learn, model-selection, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I understand Cross Validation in practice, but I'm not sure how SciKit-Learn's [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) uses it to produce an overall score/ metric for a model. For example, if I do a multi-metric evaluation, does the Cross Validation step take the mean of every metric from the split's $k$ models?

I've tried looking this up in the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#grid-search), and even dug around in SciKit-Learn's `_search` module, but I still can't find an exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Simple Answer

If you read the introduction of the [Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) for Cross Validation you will see that Cross Validation typically builds $k$ models and averages their scores. SciKit-Learn replicates this behaviour.

If you pass multiple scorers to `GridSearchCV`, like below:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
parameters = {'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}
model = HistGradientBoostingClassifier()
scorers = ['accuracy', 'f1_weighted']

clf = GridSearchCV(model, parameters, verbose=10, scoring=scorers, refit='f1_weighted')
```

`GridSearchCV` will score each $k$-fold of your candidate models with the metrics you've provided it after each fit. Then, it will take the average of the $k$-fold cross validations and store that for you for every model in its `cv_results_` attribute. To see the results, you can fit the model from the code above and display them with the following code:

```
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.cv_results_)
```

Bear in mind, when using more than one scorer, you have to deliberately select one the scorers using `GridSearchCV`'s `refit='your-scorer-choice-here'` parameter.

## Complex Answer

You mentioned digging around the code base, so I thought it might be worthwhile pointing you in the right direction.

The code you're looking for can be found in the `sklearn.module_selection._spread` module. Inside of the the abstract class `BaseSearchCV` there's a class method called `fit`. That method defines an inner function called `evaluate_candidates`, which is a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) used to run the parameter sets. Parameter sets are **"candidates"** in the model.

`evaluate_candidates` runs all the candidates in parallel, and gets an output dictionary from each model. The dictionary has the following form:

```
{'fit_error': None,
 'test_scores': {'accuracy': 0.9666666666666667, 'f1_weighted': 0.9665831244778613},
 'n_test_samples': 30,
 'fit_time': 0.19898295402526855,
 'score_time': 0.007509946823120117}
```

It returns one of these for every training round it goes through. Specifically, if you have $4$ candidate models with a $k$-fold of $5$, you'll have $20$ of these outputs. The output dictionaries are bundled in a list and returned to you.

```
[{'fit_error': None, 'test_scores': {'accuracy': 0.9666666666666667, 'f1_weighted': 0.9665831244778613}, 'n_test_samples': 30, 'fit_time': 0.14478611946105957, 'score_time': 0.0039865970611572266},
 {'fit_error': None, 'test_scores': {'accuracy': 0.9666666666666667, 'f1_weighted': 0.9665831244778613}, 'n_test_samples': 30, 'fit_time': 0.13864803314208984, 'score_time': 0.003986358642578125}
 ... ]
```

These, along with your "candidate parameters" (`candidate_params`), are added to internal lists called `all_out` and `all_candidate_params`, which are defined outside the inner function:

```
all_candidate_params.extend(candidate_params)
all_out.extend(out)
```

Finally, these are passed to `BaseSearchCV`'s `_format_results` method, along with `more_results`, which in your case will be `None`, and number of cross validation splits `n_splits`:

```
results = self._format_results(
                    all_candidate_params, n_splits, all_out, all_more_results
                )
```

This groups each candidate model's output, averages their values, and produces the results format that you see in `cv_results_`.

Hopefully that clears everything up for you. If anyone is interested in the code snippets that relate to this process, let me know and I'll post them below.